# Can geoserver (2.20.0 with i18n) ignore an invalid language parameter in capabilities request and respond with the default language?

Tags: geoserver

I am using geoserver 2.20.0 to provide wms.
I use the i18n internationalization for the wms configuration. I have also set an i18n entry with empty language for each configurable field, acting as the default translation.

Geoserver uses the default values of the title and abstract of the service, when no language parameter is used in the request.

But when I send a getcapabilities request with invalid or not supported language parameter, instead of getting the default values of title and abstract, I get an exception.

Is there a way to fix this and make geoserver respond with the default values?